# Angular JS application not working in Windows Phone WebView

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone-8

We have written a simple application that seems to be working in desktop browsers (Chrome), Android Webview and iOS Webview. However, we seem to be facing difficulty in getting it to work with Windows Phone's webview component.

We have enabled Javascript using `IsScriptEnabled="True"`.

We tried setting csp also, but that doesn't seem to be working. Could someone please help us out?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!!

this was the error which i found in emulator using window.onerror

```
[$sce:iequirks] Strict Contextual Escaping does not support Internet Explorer version < 9 in quirks mode
```

To solve this, just put `<!doctype html>` to the top of your html.
This will solve the problem.